# How to cancel all grid store XHR requests but the last [dojo dgrid]?

Tags: dojo, store, abort, dgrid

I am using [dojo dgrid  0.3.14](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Grid)

I have live search toolbar

On every user input change i do

```
    searchGrid.set("store", searchStore, query);
```

It works fine but back end returns data in no order.

So sometimes grid is being refreshed with slow previous response.

How to cancel all grid store XHR requests but the last?

current solution for DGrid is

```
   _abortQuery: function () {
       // console.log("_abortQuery" , this._refreshDeferred);
        if (this._refreshDeferred && this._refreshDeferred.cancel){
            this._refreshDeferred.cancel();
        }
        return this;
    },

    refresh: function () {
             this._abortQuery();
        return this.inherited(arguments);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're responding to user input on every keypress, I would suggest that rather than seeking to cancel requests, you instead debounce the input.  dgrid has a utility function named `debounce` in `dgrid/util/misc` for this purpose.  Debouncing refers to the practice of listening to an event, but only responding once the event has stopped firing for a certain period of time.

See https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/misc for more information.

Comment: `request 1 started at 12:00:00, returned at 12:00:10,`
               
`request 2 started at 12:00:05, returned and shown at 12:00:08.`
          how debounce help NOT to show results of request 1?